# How to mock Request.Files[] in MVC unit test class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

I want to test a controller method in MVC unit test.
For my controller method to test, I require a Request.Files[] collection with length one.
I want to mock Request.Files[] as I have used a file upload control on my view rendered by controller method. 
Can anyone please suggest how can I mock request.file collection in my unit test.

thanks,
kapil

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't mention what mocking framework you are using but here's how you would do it with Rhino Mocks:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Request.Files.Count);
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    // arrange
    var controller = new HomeController();
    var context = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpRequestBase>();
    var files = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpFileCollectionBase>();
    context.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(request);
    files.Stub(x => x.Count).Return(5);
    request.Stub(x => x.Files).Return(files);
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context, new RouteData(), controller);


    // act
    var actual = controller.Index();

    // assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(ViewResult));
    var viewResult = actual as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(viewResult.ViewData.Model, typeof(int));
    Assert.AreEqual(5, viewResult.ViewData.Model);
}
```

Remark: Using [MVCContrib.TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) this test could be greatly simplified especially the context mocking part and the asserts as well:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    // arrange
    var sut = new HomeController();
    InitializeController(sut);
    Files["test.txt"] = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpPostedFileBase>();

    // act
    var actual = sut.Index();

    // assert
    actual
        .AssertViewRendered()
        .WithViewData<int>()
        .ShouldBe(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. I am using open source mocking framework "Moq".

Answer (score 5):

[Scott Hanselman has a blog post covering this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=bc137b6b-d8d0-47d1-9795-f8814f7d1903) using Moq.