# How to mock the HTTPFileCollection without using Moq framework? (NSubstitute can be used)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

Here's a function I have to unit test:

```
uploadFiles(HttpFileCollection files)
{
for(it i=0;i<files.Count; i++)
     storeFile(files[i].FileName)
}
```

So how shall I mock this HttpFileCollection object? I have tried - to create HttpFileCollection object but it has no constructor, so couldn't create object. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Are you able to use [`HttpFileCollectionBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpfilecollectionbase?view=netframework-4.8) instead? See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700227/906) which might help.

Comment: If I use HttpFileCollectionBase, it says cannot convert HttpFileCollectionBase to HttpFileCollection. Also I cannot use any mocking framework. I checked this answer but it uses the mocking framework. Can you please provide example of how it can be done with Nsubstitute